# Basis of the subspace of $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Find a basis of the subspace of R4 consisiting of all vectors of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\
6 x_1 + x_2\\
4 x_1 + 5 x_2\\
8 x_1 - 9 x_2\end{bmatrix}$$

Now, I really have no clue how to set this up in order to find a basis. Maybe because of the way it's set up?

Any hints on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: you can split up this vector as the sum of two vectors:

$$
\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ 6x_1+x_2\\ 4x_1+5x_2\\ 8x_1-9x_2\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ 6x_1\\ 4x_1\\ 8x_1\end{array}\right]+\left[\begin{array}{c}0\\ x_2\\ 5x_2\\ -9x_2\end{array}\right]
$$
Each of these vectors only depends on one parameter.  Do you see what the basis should be now?

To see why the original format makes sense, think about the following $4\times 2$ matrix: 
$$
A=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0\\6 & 1\\4&5\\8&-9\end{array}\right]
$$If you multiply $A$ by the column vector $[x_1,x_2]^T$, you'll get exactly the original vector.  Thus by finding the basis for this set, you're essentially characterizing the range of the linear transformation from $\Bbb{R}^2$ to $\Bbb{R}^4$ defined by the matrix $A$.

Comment: lol, yea I see it now! Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason why it has been setup in such a way?

Comment: @Dimitri see edit.

Answer (score 1):

{(1,6,4,8),(0,1,5,-9)} are inedpendence and gnerate this space so they can be basis of space
independence is clear
they generate space since:
$(x_{1},6x_{1}+x_{2}, 4x_{1}+5x_{2},8x_{1}-9x_{2})=x_{1}(1,6,4,8)+x_{2}(0,1,5,-9)$

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: observe the generic vector depends only of two variables, so set once $\,x_1=1\;,\;\;x_2=0\,$ , and then set $\,x_10\;,\;\;x_2=1\,$ , and the two vectors you obtain will automatically be linearly independent *and* a basis of the wanted vector subspace (why? Can you see the wanted subspace is of dimension $\,2\,$ ?)